# transfer dictionary with key to df to one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that I am trying to transform into a single dataframe.

Currently is has key:dataframe system, as below.

```
{'lab_location-one':                      water_quality  titration
 DateTimeStamp                             
 2020-01-13 08:20:00      53.340000      50
 2020-01-13 08:25:00      53.381579      76
 2020-01-13 08:30:00      51.982143     112
 2020-01-13 08:35:00      54.372881     118
 2020-01-13 08:40:00      55.544118      68
 ...                            ...     ...
 
 
 [28242 rows x 2 columns],
 'lab_location-two':                      water_quality  titration
 DateTimeStamp                             
 2020-01-13 07:45:00      48.666667       9
 2020-01-13 07:50:00      43.504000     125
...
 
 [30626 rows x 2 columns],
 'lab_location-three':                      water_quality  titration
 DateTimeStamp                             
 2020-01-15 08:20:00      50.842105      38
 2020-01-15 08:25:00      50.905405      74
....
```

The sort of dataframe I want to work with is like this

```
DateTimeStamp   Lab water_quality   titration
15/01/2020 8:22 1   65  63
15/01/2020 8:22 1   59  58
15/01/2020 8:22 2   59  59
15/01/2020 8:22 2   59  58
15/01/2020 8:22 3   52  51
```

Using a simple pandas function on the dictionary

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_by_intervaled_group)
```

returns "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

As each of the values in the dictionary is a dataframe, should i perhaps append these together, adding a column into each dataframe for hostname, then appending each by the new hostname?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfs = []
for lab,df in data_dict.items():
    df['lab'] = lab
    dfs.append(df)
final = pandas.concat(dfs)
```

I think will work ... it basically just adds a new column then stacks them

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `concat`:

```
pd.concat(df_by_intervaled_group).reset_index()
```